# Sitecore xdb robot detection?

Tags: xdb, session-state

Actually we were facing some intermittent session timeout and someone has mentioned about Analytics.Robots.SessionTimeout . We fixed our session timeout issue by increasing the above analytics robots session timeout to 30 mins in sync with what we have for normal users session time frame. I want to understand bit more about this analytics robots and how it helps in overall user interaction.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read the documentation of robots detection on the Sitecore doc-Portal?
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/robot_detection/visitor_identification_using_robot_detection

Please check the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` cookie. If your users have the `IsClassificationGuessed` key set to true, they would be classified as a robot and the session timeout would be reduced to your `Analytics.Robots.SessionTimeout` value (default = 1min)

A user could be identified as a robot in following cases:

1. the timeout setting comparison javascript would be executed fastet than 30 seconds after document-load (see the doc link above for more details),
2. the user agent is in your "blacklist",
3. the IP-Address of your user is in your "blacklist". Robots blacklists are stored under `Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config`

The system can identify your users as a malicious robot (code = 930), as a autodetected robot (code = 925) or as a other robot type (any code value greater than 900).

If you are able to reproduce/debugging the issue, you can watch the value of `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact.System.Classification` to see the actual classification of the current user (or made a processor to log the value to your log-system).

Comment: @szymon Sorry for being so crude but the above document by sitecore helps.

Comment: @SantoshPoojari I'm happy to hear that!